# How to implement business logic in MVC 5 with EF6

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, entity-framework-6, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I've read the [MVC5 with EF6 DB First tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/creating-the-web-application).  With this tutorial, it will generate code (controller and view).

I have created 3 *projects* in VS:

```
+ AdminWebSite
+ PublicWebSite
+ EntityFramework
```

And I've question, where should I implement the business logic, and share it will multiple website (Admin & Public)?

The business logic may include:

- Logic with database (i.e. Transaction with multi-table)
- Logic with SharePoint info
- Logic with Email Server

**EDIT**

Typo, should be 3 projects instead of 3 solution, but it should be similar case, which `AdminWebSite` and `PublicWebSite` have add `EntityFramework` as reference.

**EDIT 2**

Before the MVC3, I will create a class project which includes all business logic, and also the Repository class.  So that every `WebSite` or `WebServices` can use the same business logic (but I'm not sure is it the best practice).

But when move to MVC5 with EF6, the repository and unit of work seems gone.  And don't want to implement repository for every table, which some tables just for direct CRUD without business logic.

I hope this can clarify the is `Too broad`.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in to this:
http://dombrovsky.github.io/EntityHooks/

It looks like a framework that is designed to work with EF6. It should allow you to write custom business logic when a certain event occurs like when a record is inserted, or updated.

Comment: Thanks, but the hooks is designed for _Code First_, but I'm using `Database First`... And it hook the database action, not related to business logic

Comment: EntityHooks is just an example of how business logic may be implemented. If you have a look at the code in the Git Repo, you can see how code is built around events occurring. You don't have to use the code, but you can use the same techniques/patterns to implement custom logic for business. With some abstraction, you can store custom hooks in external assemblies that may differ from customer to customer.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize **Projects** under a solution.

I usually have the database layer in a separate project (Class library/DLL) and let other projects refer to it. This way you have only one copy of the ORM (Entity Framework) simplifying any changes in the database model. I also create a database project (if SQL server) that holds the actual schema definitions including tables and stored procedures. This is a great way to make changes in the schema and deploying it.

Anytime a significant enough portion of the code can be re-used it is usually a good idea to make it a class library and have client projects refer to it.

Comment: Can you explain more about that? Database Project should be same as Entity Framework, right? And which project should I implement the business logic?

Comment: Database project is not the entity framework project. You can create a new type of project called SQL Server project from Visual Studio new project templates. It stores stuff that goes inside the actual SQL server database. Things like tables, stored procedures and other SQL level resources. I find it extremely convenient to use this project for version control of SQL resources, comparing schema (e.g. between production and local) and applying migrations.

Comment: Business logic could go either in Controller layer, Model layer inside Entity framework model project (mentioned in my answer) or in SQL stored procedure. Based on my experiences, having logic in stored procedures can make managing business logic easier (if the logic is not too long) faster (performance wise).

Answer (score 0):

One solution include Web project 、BLL project 、 DAL project，web project contains publish and admin

Answer (score 0):

I would not have a project named EntityFramework, I would suggest that you replace this project with a project named Infrastructure. This infrastructure project would contain classes that depends on external sources like EmailSenders and DAL classes like EntityFramework classes and other stuff that you for some reason in the future might want to replace with other external services.

Your business logic should be stored in a Core project. This core project would not reference either the web projects or the infrastructure project (but the web projects would reference both the infrastructure as well as the core project). If you need an EmailSender in the core project you reference an interface like IEmailSender, which is located in core as well.

This is basically  the structure I would suggest:

- AdminWebSite
- PublicWebSite
- Infrastructure

  - EF
  - Log
  - Messages
  - SharePoint
- Core
- Test (This project contains all your unit and integration tests)

I really suggest that you read up on using Dependency injection. When you understand DI, the separation of core and infrastructure will make sense and you see how these can use each other without any hard references.

If you dont want to use UoW or Repositories, I would suggest that you move EF to core but the infrastructure project is still very much valid for other external services.